Error when using CoroutineCrudRepository in Spring Boot 3.2.4
I just created a new Spring Boot project using spring initializr
Specification:

Project: Maven
Language: Kotlin
Spring Boot 3.2.4
Project Metadata

Group: com.michaelrenops
Artifact: demo
Name: demo
Description: demo
Package name: com.michaelrenops.demo
Packaging: Jar
Java: 17


Dependencies:

Spring Reactive Web
Spring Data Reactive MongoDB
Spring Data Reactive Redis

Model



    @Documents("accounts")
    class AccountModel(
        @Id
        var id: String? = null,
    
        val name: String,
    
        @CreatedDate
        var createdAt: Instant? = null,
    
        @LastModifiedDate
        var updatedAt: Instant? = null
    )

Repository
    @Repository
    interface AccountRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<AccountModel, String>

Service
    @Service
    class AccountService(
        private val accountRepository: AccountRepository
    ) {
        suspend fun create(body: CreateAccountBody) = accountRepository.save(body.toAccountModel())
    }

Controller
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("account")
    class AccountController(
        private val accountService: AccountService
    ) {
        @PostMapping
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
        suspend fun create(
            @RequestBody body: CreateAccountBody
        ) = accountService.create(body)
    }

DemoApplication
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ConfigurationPropertiesScan
    @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
    @EnableReactiveMongoAuditing
    class DemoApplication
    
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
    }

POM.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.michaelrenops</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>demo</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
            <kotlin.version>1.9.23</kotlin.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
            <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                        </args>
                        <compilerPlugins>
                            <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        </compilerPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>

When I start the application I get this error


APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in
com.michaelrenops.demo.service.AccountService required a bean of type
'com.michaelrenops.demo.repository.AccountRepository' that could not
be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type
'com.michaelrenops.demo.repository.AccountRepository' in your
configuration.
Process finished with exit code 1


Will interface AccountRepository : define the repository with public access from other packages (I'm no Kotlin expert) ?

I think it should, also I added the annotation @Repository. I have another project with Spring Boot 3.2.2 and it works, but not in 3.2.4. Am I missing something?

I encountered the same error, try the steps below.

Add the following annotation in your application class @EnableR2dbcRepositories.

Extend R2dbcRepository class instead of CoroutineCrudRepository class. Make sure your import is org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository


